# Htacces RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have this code in my `.htaccess` working fine:

```
(ex. RewriteRule "^new-jersey/(.*)" "location.php?c=$1" [NC,L])
```

This can be accessed at `/new-jersey/city_example`

However, if I add a simple `-second-version` at the end, it no longer works:

```
(ex. RewriteRule "^new-jersey/(.*)-second-version" "location.php?c=$1" [NC,L])
```

My goal is to access this at `/new-jersey/city_example-second-version`

Comment: put the new rule before the old rule, htaccess is sensitive to order

Comment: i couldn't seem to get it working after 2 weeks, could you please provide an example? would appreciate it tons!

Comment: got a feeling its impossible :/... its ok, i think there may be a bypass

if i

Comment: if i could perhaps give the value in the database a temporary name. such as adding "-second-version" to each city so it looks like "city_example-second-version"